# commandButton issue

Tags: oracle-adf

Currently I have a two commandButtons:

- one to execute a validation using actionlistener that populates a Return.inputValue
- and another to move the return value from the previous listener to a
  pageflowscope variable as below

```
<amx:commandButton text="commandButton1" id="cb4" action="godecide">
  <amx:setPropertyListener from="#{bindings.Return.inputValue}" type="action" to="#{pageFlowScope.ReturnValue}"/>
</amx:commandButton>
<amx:commandButton actionListener="#{bindings.CheckUser.execute}" text="CheckUser"
                   disabled="#{!bindings.CheckUser.enabled}" id="cb3"/>
```

How can achieve this with one command button please?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can call a method in the button action and within that method take the value from Return, set this value whenever you want and then redirect the page to some other page. As you want to have this value in pageFlowScope, define the scope of the bean in adfc-config as pageFlow or I thing Session should be fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches:

1. Do everything you need within the taskflow action. Thats the action you have described in first button, you can add method call, used in the second button as a listener.
2. Do all the job in your bean. Set actionListener in the button, that will handle all the work needed to be done.

In both cases you can keep propertyListener to set this value.

Give more details on the case, if you need further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

in first command button execute method via action which will your required task and in actionListner pass that generated value to other manager that is fine.
by this you no need to use sesssion moreover session are havey.